# Angular ng-sidebar error

Tags: angular, plugins, webpack

I installed new plugin for **angular 5** **ng-sidebar** and done all steps but it is not work as well as it shows in documentation and [**Click This for seeing error**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l93oG.png)

```
 Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'opened' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-sidebar'.
1. If 'opened' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

  <!-- A sidebar -->
  <ng-sidebar [ERROR ->][(opened)]="_opened">
    <p>Sidebar contents</p>
  </ng-sidebar>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@4:14
'ng-sidebar' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

  <!-- A sidebar -->
  [ERROR ->]<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened">
    <p>Sidebar contents</p>
  </ng-sidebar>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@4:2
'ng-sidebar-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-sidebar-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-sidebar-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
[ERROR ->]<ng-sidebar-container>

  <!-- A sidebar -->
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@1:0`enter code here`
```

Comment: did you defined `private _opened: boolean = false;` in class ? and define SidebarModule.forRoot() in your app.module.

Comment: I toke a photo please click  on top this link   I'll get following error.